# No shutdown or reboot option in KDE4's menu

Tags: arch-linux, systemd

I obviously have the privilege to shutdown through dbus, cuz it works in XFCE4, but in KDE4, I only have an option to logout.

Any thoughts?

I start kde4 with `dbus-launch --exit-with-session startkde`

**EDIT**

Yes, I got `Active=yes` from systemctl, but removing the dbus-launch stopped docky from launching, and .. shutdown option still not available

Answer (score 2):

Using `dbus-launch` is no longer needed with systemd. You need to make sure that when running `startx` that `Xwindows` is launched on the say `TTY`. This will insure that you preserve the login session. Below I've listed some notes on setting up systemd --user sessions.

#### startx

Users should first set up systemd-logind to manage their session. If systemd is running as the system init daemon, then this is already happening.

Next, the user must launch systemd by putting the following in their `~/.xinitrc.`

```
systemd --user
```

If the user is not launching the window manager through systemd --user, then

```
systemd --user &
```

*should* be used and launched like anything else in `~/.xinitrc`, before execing the window manager.

After starting `X`, the user can check whether their session is now being managed by systemd-logind with the following command:

```
$ loginctl --no-pager show-session $XDG_SESSION_ID | grep Active
```

If this command prints `Active=yes`, then the user is now using `systemd-logind` to manage their session. **The user should remove any instances of ck-launch-session or dbus-launch from their ~/.xinitrc**, as those commands are **unneeded**.

[More information on this can be found here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/User)

Comment: No luck, see my updates

Comment: are you running `systemd --user` in your .xinitrc

Comment: It blocks, so I ran `systemd --user &` instead, prior to `startkde`

Comment: Place `systemd --user &` in your `.xinitrc` and remove **all** `dbus` related lines. So your `.xinitrc` should show. `systemd --user & <newline> exec startkde

Comment: If this does not work. Then install KDM and `systemctl enable kdm.service` (to enable starting at boot) followed by `systemctl start kdm.service`. Or you could just reboot and test that the `service unit` starts at boot.